# What is the most appropriate way to read the JPEG comment from a JPEG using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, npm, jpeg

What is the right way to read the JPEG comment field (*not EXIF*, but the [COM field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure)) from a JPEG using JavaScript, specifically using node on the command line?

I have found numerous libraries for reading EXIF data in JavaScript, but I have yet to find one for JPEG comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scan the input stream for COM marker. The only trick is that you need to identify the markers with length fields and skip over them.

Comment: Thanks, this answer got me thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user3344003 above I got to this solution using [node-binary](https://github.com/substack/node-binary):

```
var binary = require('binary');

binary.parse(buffer)
  // Scan for COM marker 0xfffe
  .scan('precomment', new Buffer([0xff, 0xfe]))

  // Get the next two bytes for the size of the comment field
  .word16bu('size')

  // Put the comment field in a buffer
  .buffer('comment', 'size')

  // Do something with the buffer
  .tap(function (vars) {
    console.log(vars.comment.toString('utf-8'));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the solution above is that it does not take account of other segments (as hinted at in the original answer). You need to guard against other occurrences of 0xFF 0xFE for example in other parameter sections or in the compressed image data, otherwise you run the risk of extracting arbitrary binary data.

Furthermore, the COM segments are also used by some apps to hold non-text data so in my experience it's better to use `util.TextDecoder` and drop segments which are not 100% valid UTF-8 (or encoding of your choice).

I wrote [rdjpgcom.js](https://github.com/inukshuk/rdjpgcom.js) because I ran into these issues myself, so you can now just use that if you need to extract text comments.